# Applying Riemann–Liouville derivative to Lorenz 3D equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, differential-equations, derivative

I am using a module in python *differint* to solve the system of Lorenz 3D equation. After running my 3D system over differint ==> Riemann-Liouville operator for *alpha value 1* the original equation and Riemann-Liouville results are not same . The code is mentioned below

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import differint.differint as df

t = np.arange(1 , 50, 0.01)

def Lorenz(state,t):
  # unpack the state vector
  x = state[0]
  y = state[1]
  z = state[2]

  a=10;b=8/3;c=28 
  xd = a*(y -x) 
  yd = - y +c*x - x*z
  zd = -b*z + x*y

  return [xd,yd,zd]
state0 = [1,1,1]

state = odeint(Lorenz, state0, t)
#Simple lorentz eqaution plot
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(state[:,0],state[:,1])
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(state[:,0],state[:,2])
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(state[:,1],state[:,2])
plt.show()

DF = df.RL(1, state, 0, len(t), len(t)) 
# Riemann-Liouville plots
state=DF
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(state[:,0],state[:,1])
plt.subplot(2,2, 2)
plt.plot(state[:,0],state[:,2])
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(state[:,1],state[:,2])
plt.show()
```

**Am i making mistake anywhere or this is the true result?**

[image]

**as you can see in eqaution (2) when we put α = 1 we will get the results same as of non fractional system (1). Interested in calculating equation (3) for different values of alpha**

I think this **perhaps** the idea of mine is incorrect, because what i am doing is first calculating the system of differential equation using

```
state = odeint(Lorenz, state0, t)
```

followed by the *differint* module

```
DF = df.RL(1, state, 0, len(t), len(t))
```

**Graphs for lorenz eqaution**

[image]

**Graphs for RL fractional for alpha = 1**
[image]

in these graphs as u can see that the trajectories are absolutely same but the scaling become different

Comment: What exactly is the exact result? Or why do you expect to get the same result after applying a fractional differentiation operation of order 1?

Comment: updated my question .. and yes its LORENZ Dynamical CHOAS system

Comment: KNOCK KNOCK HELO @LutzLehmann

Comment: You still have not said why you expect identical results. Or otherwise what the expected results are. I have the suspicion that yours is more a mathematical problem, not a programming problem. I'm not very conversant in fractional derivatives, but there might be some experts on math.SE

Comment: SO, in your opinion the code is technically correct, but perhaps there is some issue in my understanding regarding the fractional derivative.?
Plus if there is some mathematical understanding issue. Can u recon some one to me who can help me solving this ?

Comment: Yes, along those lines. As I said above, you did not say much about what the expected results are, perhaps some reference for the expected identity. math.SE and scicomp.SE have infrquently such questions, but I'm not sure about how many of them were answered.

Comment: mathematically speaking if i put alpha = 1 in equation 2 and solve the function f(x) for lorenz the equation 1 graphical results and equation 2 graphical results must remains same, fortunately the expected results are absolutely same  but the thing which makes me anxious is the graphs scaling . let me update my question with graphical illustration.

Comment: Your question now looks complete. Are you sure about the last 3 parameters in df.RL? Per the description in https://pypi.org/project/differint/ they should be `a,b,N` for a sequence as in `np.linspace(a,b,N)`. So I would expect `...,0,t[-1],len(t))`. What I do not understand is that the images look indeed similar, as `DF` should contain an approximation for the first derivatives, and so far the equations do not get solved in the fractional derivative version.

Comment: def RL(alpha, f_name, domain_start = 0.0, domain_end = 1.0, num_points = 100):

Comment: hahah i solved my own question by doing this
DF = df.RL(1, state, 0, len(t)*3, len(t))

Comment: Yes, and your value for `domain_end` is strange. The `t` array ends at 50 with `len(t)` about 5000, so there is a clear difference.

Comment: But is that a solution or a hack? A better picture would be given by comparing the component graphs over time.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmm let me do that by plotting the time domains of both

Comment: well its look fine to me .... comon bro like my answer this is the first time i answer my own question ... :D

Comment: and this is not some coincidence i tried it for different n-dimensional equations ( 4D and 5D) and by putting len(t) * n for them, is working absolutely fine as well for those equations

Comment: deleting my answer because it is incorrect. stuck again in the fractional differentiation problem

Answer (score 0):

The call to DF.RL requires a function of the differential equation, however, you used the solution to a differential equation - state (output of odeint call).  From the package site https://pypi.org/project/differint/

```
def f(x):
  return x**0.5

DF = df.RL(0.5, f)
print(DF)
```

Can you try `DF = df.RL(1, Lorenz, 0, len(t), len(t))` ?

Comment: no this will give error